# Value true at action of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to get "action" value of the json response and show it with a textview,
here is my json :

{"action":"true"}

and here is my java code

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {


                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("action");
                String message = object.getString("action");

                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                }

                txtproductsenf.setText(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

But i'm getting nothing in my textview and i got this in Android Monitor :

"Value true at action of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

how can i fix this?

Comment: `action` is not a JSONarray...use `object.getString("action");`

Comment: Have you getting only one "action" json object?

Comment: Just wondering... what is the purpose of the `for` loop? It's not doing anything.

Comment: I think you have not basic aware of JSON parsing.

Comment: You better stick to the Java Naming Conventions. Variable names should start with a lowercase letter!

Answer (score 1):

It is faliling because of this line:

```
JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("action");
```

`action` is actually a JSON object whereas you are trying to cast it into `JSONArray`, hence the `Exception`.

Below should work:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
String message = object.getString("action");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"action":"true"}
```

It has only json Object not json array so you will parse this json String as follows

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {


                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = object.getString("action");
                txtproductsenf.setText(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```